# ошибка python multiple statements found while compiling a single statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

код:

```
koloda = [6,7,8,9,10,2,3,4,11] * 4
import random
random.shuffle(koloda)
print('Поиграем в очко?')
count = 0
while True:
    choice = input('Будете брать карту? y/n\n')
    if choice == 'y':
        current = koloda.pop()
        print('Вам попалась карта достоинством %d' %current)
        count += current
        if count > 21:
            print('Извините, Вы проиграли')
            break
        elif count == 21:
            print('Поздравляем с победой')
            break
        else:
            print(' У Вас %d очков' %count)
            break
    else:
        print('Ну как хотите')
        break
print('До новых встреч!')
```

Comment: А при каких условиях вылетает ошибка?

Comment: при нажатии enter

Comment: У меня все нормально скопмилировалось) И с `y`, и с `n`, и с просто `enter` нормально отрабатывает

Comment: Мой внутренний телепат подсказывает, что это попытка скопипастить код в интерпретатор IDLE

Comment: это не из за версии? у меня python 3.6.0 shell

Comment: andreymal  да я копировал туда

Comment: ну во первых так делать не нужно, а во вторых - зачем вам `break` после любого действия? а если я хочу и вторую карту взять? дайте поиграть человеку..

Comment: после вывода текущих очков игрока замените `break` на `continue` и будет вам счастье

Comment: Спасибо сейчас попробую

Comment: и еще break нужно после каждого действия просто убирать или везде заменять его на continue?

Answer (score 1):

Цикл While прерывается потому что надо убрать break в это части

```
else:
    print(' У Вас %d очков' %count)
    break
```